# How can I extend my google appengine application to run a windows executable?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a simple webapp running on Google App Engine (python). I want to extend the functionality of my my webapp and this requires running a Windows executable on a user uploaded JPG file. This cannot be done on App Engine.

Thoughts I've had are to stick the executable on a server somewhere, figure out how to put a python wrapper around it and dial into it with appengine when I need to. I've only been exposed to relatively simple App Engine environment and only know python so I was wondering if someone could suggest some ideas as to the best (and quickest) way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best off running a Windows machine in the cloud, using Amazon's EC2, or renting a VPS (Virtual Private Server).

Neither are really quick, though with [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2) there is lots of documentation.